# Sublime text 3 plugin development for custom autocomplete like emmet?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I would like to create my custom plugin like emmet for auto completion and tag expansion for html tags like `h2>span` .myclass should result in  `<div class="myclass"></div>`.

I started with but didn't find any documentation for tracking the user type event and how to define scope for plugin to be only applied for html files.

When i tried to use print statement inside my class it throws syntax error

```
def run(self, edit):
  print "i am in run"
  self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

How can i debug my plugin code without print statement or is there any alternative for sublime plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, one doesn't program a plugin to track what the user types in Sublime Text, but instead binds a command to a keybinding. Then, when the user presses that certain key, under certain conditions, defined in the context of the keybinding, the command executes and looks at the text near the selection caret.

Sublime Text plugins are developed in Python 3, where `print` is not a statement, but a function. Therefore, you need to use `print('I am in "run"')` to output debug messages to the ST console.

For example, if this was your plugin code:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ThisIsAnExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print('I am in the "run" method of "ThisIsAnExampleCommand"')
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

then you might define a keybinding like:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "this_is_an_example",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

which would operate when the user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but only if all selections are empty, and the syntax of the current file being edited is HTML.

Your plugin could look at `self.view.sel()` to get the selection/caret position(s).